# Efficiently processing DataFrame rows with a Python function?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

In many places in our Pandas-using code, we have some Python function `process(row)`. That function is used over `DataFrame.iterrows()`, taking each `row`, and doing some processing, and returning a value, which we ultimate collect into a new `Series`.

I realize this usage pattern circumvents most of the performance benefits of the numpy / Pandas stack.

1. What would be the best way to make this usage pattern as efficient
   as possible?
2. Can we possibly do it without rewriting most of our code?

Another aspect of this question: can all such functions be converted to a numpy-efficient representation?  I've much to learn about the numpy / scipy / Pandas stack, but it seems that for truly arbitrary logic, you may sometimes need to just use a slow pure Python architecture like the one above. Is that the case?

Comment: If you are doing math, you should be able to do vectorized operations. If you are using strings or other non fixed-size datatypes, you could do the math on numbers in a vecorized way, then do row-based for the rest... can you provide some detail on what you're doing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should apply your function along the axis=1. Function will receive a row as an argument, and anything it returns will be collected into a new series object

```
df.apply(you_function, axis=1)
```

Example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(3),
                       'b': np.random.rand(3)})
>>> df
   a         b
0  0  0.880075
1  1  0.143038
2  2  0.795188
>>> def func(row):
        return row['a'] + row['b']
>>> df.apply(func, axis=1)
0    0.880075
1    1.143038
2    2.795188
dtype: float64
```

As for the second part of the question: row wise operations, even optimised ones, using pandas `apply`, are not the fastest solution there is. They are certainly **a lot** faster than a python for loop, but not the fastest. You can test that by timing operations and you'll see the difference.

Some operation could be converted to column oriented ones (one in my example could be easily converted to just `df['a'] + df['b']`), but others cannot. Especially if you have a lot of branching, special cases or other logic that should be perform on your row. In that case, if the `apply` is too slow for you, I would suggest *"Cython-izing"* your code. Cython plays really nicely with the NumPy C api and will give you the maximal speed you can achieve.

Or you can try [numba](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/06/15/numba-vs-cython-take-2/). :)

Comment: Small typo in `applay` :)

Comment: @PhillipCloud I saw that you rarely use apply along `axis=1`. Is there any specific performance reason? Shouldn't that be the fastest way to itterate over the array row wise?

Comment: I believe it is. No particular reason, I just usually work with data that are column oriented so I end up not having to use it (so it's not really at the top of my mind). I also have a suspicion that operations along rows can be avoided most of the time by some kind of reshaping or `groupby` operation, but I have no evidence to back that up, just my intuition which could be wrong here.

Comment: That's true, if you can convert your operation to column oriented one, it's way faster. Thanks.

Comment: token link to the enhancing performance section of the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/enhancingperf.html

Comment: Late to the party here, but would it be correct to say that, by using `axis=1`, you get the same performance as if you had oriented your data via columns while preserving the row-based format?