# Is there a better way to compute the average of a row in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with **"n"** rows and **"m"** columns and I want the average of the **first** row and **m-1** columns.

```
              c1        c2        c3   . . . . . . . cm
r1
r2
r3
.
.
.
.
rn
```

I am currently summing the entire first row, subtracting the last column value corresponding to this row and then averaging it out. The code looks like this:

```
    (sum(df.ix["r1",:]) - df.ix["r1",'cm'])/(len(df.columns)-1)
```

Would you advise an alternative to accomplish my goal?

Comment: You can use [apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)  as stated in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282988/efficiently-processing-dataframe-rows-with-a-python-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe something like

```
df[df.columns[:-1]].mean(axis=1)
```

will do the trick, given you have this flat dataframe structure.

Here, `df.columns[:-1]` returns an Index pointing to all the columns except the last one.

*UPD*
Pardon, that will give you all the rows computed, you still have to select the one you want (the first one)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.iloc[0][:-1].mean()` like that:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[7,8,9]}) 
df.iloc[0][:-1].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with `mean`:

```
print (df.iloc[:, :-1].mean(axis=1))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[2,2,3],
                   'c':[2,5,6]}, index=['r1','r2','r3'])

print (df)
    a  b  c
r1  1  2  2
r2  2  2  5
r3  3  3  6

print (df.iloc[:, :-1].mean(axis=1))
r1    1.5
r2    2.0
r3    3.0
dtype: float64
```